# Serializing null values with jackson

Tags: java, serialization, nullpointerexception, null, jackson

I'm trying to serialize through jackson some fields, which can be null, with a custom serializer. Reading online it seems that jackson should write a "null" string, and if I want a different output I should follow this example [from its official github](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/JacksonHowToCustomSerializers#converting-null-values-to-something-else)

The problem is that I get a NullPointerException instead of a "null" string.
This occurs both with JsonGenerator.writeNumberField, both with JsonGenerator.writeStringField.
To write an empty string should I manage the exception, or is there something I'm missing?

This is the stacktrace:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: [no message for java.lang.NullPointerException]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider._wrapAsIOE(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:509) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider._serialize(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:482) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:319) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._configAndWriteValue(ObjectMapper.java:3905) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.writeValueAsString(ObjectMapper.java:3219) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]
    at petmenu.restControllers.ProdottoController.thirdStageInput(ProdottoController.java:92) ~[main/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209) ~[spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136) ~[spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:891) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:974) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:877) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:851) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:806) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_202]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_202]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_202]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at petmenu.CustomProdottoSerializer.serialize(CustomProdottoSerializer.java:32) ~[main/:na]
    at petmenu.CustomProdottoSerializer.serialize(CustomProdottoSerializer.java:1) ~[main/:na]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider._serialize(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:480) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]
    ... 58 common frames omitted
```

And this is the interesting code

```java
   @Override
    public void serialize(
      Prodotto prod, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider serializer) throws IOException {
        jgen.writeStartObject();

//      getPeso_netto returns an Integer, that in the example is null
        jgen.writeNumberField("peso_netto", prod.getPeso_netto());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i would suggest to simply make a null check, or as you sugested, handle via exception.

```java
@Override
    public void serialize(
      Prodotto prod, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider serializer) throws IOException {
        jgen.writeStartObject();

//      getPeso_netto returns an Integer, that in the example is null
        if (prod.getPeso_netto() != null)
            jgen.writeNumberField("peso_netto", prod.getPeso_netto());
        else {
            jgen.writeNullField("peso_netto");     
        }
```

#### EDIT Explanation

the method JsonGenerator.writeNumberField has following method body:

```java
public final void writeNumberField(String fieldName, int value) throws IOException {
    this.writeFieldName(fieldName);
    this.writeNumber(value);
}
```

as you see, the method is expecting an int, not an Integer. The compiler is trying to Autobox the Integer to an int.
This fails with an NPE, because the Integer is a null object. So the NPE is not thrown 'by code of jackson library', but from the JVM at the point trying to pass an autoboxed null value as an int to a jackson method.

You can test this behaviour with following snippet:

```java
Integer x = null;
x = 1 + x; // will throw NPE
```

Comment: Well, I'd try/catch the writeNumberField method, but the problem is that's not it throwing the NPE, but an IOException. That's why I suspect I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: So there is a new Exception? Can you update your question with an edit and the new code/exception?

Comment: I'm sorry. I think I've not been clear in my last comment: writeNumberField throws IOException [https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonGenerator.html#writeNumberField(java.lang.String,%20int)]
Then I really can't understand where the NullPointerException comes from.

Comment: I'm not sure if i get your point. Lets try. You can use multiple Exceptions in a catch with `catch (IOException | NullPointerException e) {}`. Due to NPEs are RuntimeExceptions the compiler doesnt force you to use try/catch. But he forces you to handle the IOException. But you can just add the NPE as written above, so you will catch the NPE.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. It's been really useful, but I want to understand why jackson throws a NPE even if none of its method is supposed to do that, and why it doesn't simply write "null" as I read online by other users.

Comment: Because NPEs are RuntimeException. This means you don't have to declare them in the method body with `throws`. Thusfore it's not mentioned in any docs. The reason for this is, that 99% of the situations where a object is null, it is not expected from the programmer. If he knows that an object can be null, he makes an null check, or catches itself with try/catch.

Comment: i added an explanation for the NPE in your case in my answer edit.

Comment: Are you saying that the NPE is not thrown by jackson, but by the JVM trying to autobox? That would make sense. Then if I'd rewrite my Prodotto class to use an int instead of an Integer (ipothetically, i don't want to do that) I would get the expected behaviour: jackson that writes "null". Correct?

Comment: Yes for the first. JVM is throwing the NPE.
But changing Integer to int would not help, because a primitive type in java can never be null. they all have default values. Therefore jackson would write a `"0"` to the field, not null. Only way is to check null for yourself.

Comment: Perfect. I did already know that primitives cannot be null and cannot explain the behaviour I was reading around. The answer is simple: they were talking about writeFieldString, that obviously accept a String, that in Java is not a primitive but an Object, thus doesn't trigger any autoboxing mechanism. In that case, jackson print "null". Thanks a lot for your help. I'll mark your original answer as accepted.